# Must medical providers/businesses give a copy of a patient's medical record to the patient if the patient requests it in France?

Tags: medical, france, data-ownership, data

In the US, medical providers must by law give a copy of a patient's medical record to the patient within 30 days if the patient requests it, according to [45 CFR 164.524(b)(2)](https://www.hhs.gov/hipaa/for-professionals/privacy/guidance/access/index.html#:%7E:text=Timeliness%20in%20Providing%20Access,164.524(b)(2).):

> Timeliness in Providing Access: In providing access to the individual, a covered entity must provide access to the PHI requested, in whole, or in part (if certain access may be denied as explained below), no later than 30 calendar days from receiving the individual's request. See 45 CFR 164.524(b)(2). The 30 calendar days is an outer limit and covered entities are encouraged to respond as soon as possible.

I wonder whether a similar law exists in France.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, see https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F12210.

*The rest of the answer is a partial summary in English of what that link says. If you can read French, go read the link instead. service-public.fr is a government website, hence it is unlikely to be taken down; it is generally accurate, up-to-date, and includes links to the relevant law statutes.*

Any individual can request access their own medical records from whichever health provider produced them.

When those records are "fresh" (less than 5 years old), access must be granted at most 8 days after the request but at least 48h after it ("délai de réflexion" / thinking time).

"Access" means you can consult the files on-premise for free, but the health provider can charge you to make any copies or mail them.